# How to analyze those so many CRM 2011 performance counters?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a on-premise CRM 2011. And I have found many performance counters at below link to collect the CRM performance data.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27119

But how should I analyze the collected data? Is there any formal bentchmark/guideline/tool to help with the assessment? If I know the rules to analyze these perf counters, it is possible to automate the analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to eventually come up with a system that reads all the counters and automatically decides if your system is running well, or badly, and so you need to know what counters will tell you what "well" or "badly" means.

I'm probably not the first person to say this but "well" is almost impossible to define in a way that makes sense for all sites, all the time.  For example, if your system handles 10K requests per second successfully, is that good or bad?  Impossible to know without understanding your deployment.

You can, at least, get some *basic* indications of when things are going badly.  Check the counters marked as Faulted, Failed or Errors and see if they can be reduced to zero, or at least, to a threshold percentage that you and your business are happy with.  For example, it might be OK to have a non-zero count of authentication failures, but not to have too many as it might be evidence of an attack or a misconfiguration.  But what is "too many"?  If you are a small biz, 2 failed auths a second over a five minute period would be a worry.  If you are American Airlines, that's probably business as usual.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. And currently I am focusing on the counters related to failures.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if you mean analyzing in the sense of benchmarking or in the sense of monitoring. So below see the interpretation regarding monitoring.

For Dynamics CRM 4 there was a [test-bench](http://crmperftoolkit.codeplex.com/) which was [adopted to Dynamics CRM 2011](http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/applications/performance-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-12884915630).

---

In case you have a System Center deployment at your company, the [System Center Management Pack for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26795) would be helpful to evaluate the metrics of Dynamics CRM. You should be able to trigger alerts when certain metrics hit specific thresholds.

If you don't have a System Center deployment, you could also use another monitoring solution like for example [Nagios](http://www.nagios.com/).

The last option would be to develop a custom program which reads the performance counters and stores the historic values, in order to be able to evaluate the information.

Comment: Thanks ccellar. I have collected much performance data through the CRM 2011 counters. The question is, I don't know where to find a formal metric for all these counters. I need this metric to further analyze the collected data, possibly I can automate the process.

Comment: The CRM performance toolkit seems not fit the workflow of my business. We have a deeply customized solution.

Comment: @smwikipedia like KingZoingo mentioned in his answer, it's hard to tell which metrics should be in a certain range. What you can monitor for sure are the counters which report failed requests, etc. Another interesting would be the detection of spikes

Comment: Thanks, I think that's a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation there are two counters with recommended thresholds :

> **Server\Script Error Reports :** This component returns the total number
>   of error reports generated by the web client as well as  Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM for the Outlook client. This counter is reset weekly to
>   zero. This counter is an indicator of high script error frequency. If
>   a large number of error reports are received in a short time, the
>   Operations team should investigate to determine which pages are
>   producing errors. It is recommend that you set a monitoring alert to
>   notify you if there are ***more than 500 error reports in a 10-minute***
>   period. Note: This component has "Count statistic as difference "
>   enabled. It will return the difference between two polling intervals.
>   **CRM Authentication\WindowsAuthenticationFailuresInTheLastMinute :** There are several possible causes for authentication failure. For
>   example, the user may have been authenticated successfully by Active
>   Directory but Microsoft Dynamics CRM authentication failed to
>   communicate with the Kerberos servers, or a token expired, or the
>   user's credentials are incorrect. This counter measures the entire
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM deployment including all organizations. A high
>   count may indicate that the system is possibly under a Denial of
>   Service attack, or there is some problem with the Authentication
>   service configuration. We recommend that you set a monitoring alert to
>   notify you if this value ***exceeds 30***.

[ActiveXperts's MS Dynamics CRM 2011](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.activexperts.com/admin/dynamics/crm/#select&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGoRTL9afkel5cr91SKlDfxUzedtA) predefined check can give you 4 more predefined thresholds (you have to install the trial version to get the values).
If you can use Windows Event Logs, take a look at this [SolarWinds SAM template](http://www.solarwinds.com/NetPerfMon/SolarWinds/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=SolarWinds&file=OrionAPMMSDynamics2011Events.htm).